# Proving that average treatment effect for RDD with multiple cutoffs is a weighted average of the causal effect at each cutoff

Tags: mathematical-statistics, econometrics, causality, instrumental-variables, regression-discontinuity

**Let $Xi$ denote the original running variable and $Ci$ be the cutoff that unit $i$ faces (e.g., the nearest cutoff).**

For simplicity, I consider a case where the binary treatment is assigned if $Xi$ crosses the threshold

[image]

Further, let's denote the potential outcome at each threshold $c$ as $Yic(d)$. Finally, the standardized running variable is given by

[image]

Also, consider the following estimand:

[image]

**I would appreciate any help to prove that:**

**Given the following conditions:**

[image]

**Under the assumptions (in addition to standard RDD assumptions):**

[image]

**These three equalities below are true:**

[image]

for

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.